# How can I evaluate the value of multiple variables in an If Statement using AND and OR in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

First off, I am not a pro developer (yet), and hope someone could perhaps give me some input on a subject that seams easy, but it's not so easy.

**How can I evaluate the value of multiple `variables` in a single `IF statement`?**

This is something that still makes me scratch my head. I have seen others use it, but it is as if I am missing out on something. I have read an article about it, and looked at a `logical operator` app. Still frying my brain though.

**Example:** (Pseudo Code) if A is not B and A is not C, do something.

```
if(A !== B && A !== C) {
  // Do Something
}
```

or

```
if(A !== B || A !== C) {
  // Do Something
}
```

Which do I use? or is the answer perhaps NONE?

Comment: What's wrong with those? The first one is what you're looking for I guess. You can also do it like `if(![B, C].includes(a))`

Comment: You spelled it by yourself `if A is not B and A is not C`. First one with && is what you are looking for.

Comment: There's a huge difference in those to statements: The first will only evaluate to true if both conditions are met, the second one if either or are met.. Here's a [good article](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: The second one is "if A is not B **or** A is not C, do something." I have a feeling this isn't so much about which operator to use but more about what the above expression means exactly, since it's not easy to find a matching real-world analogy off the top of your head. I'd also advise you not to throw NOT in the mix until you have a firm handle on the basic operators. The difference between `A === B && A === C` and `A === B || A === C` is much easier to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code within the brackets will execute if the condition evaluates to `true` (or any loosely typed *truthy* value).

Consider `A = 1; B = 2; C = 1;`

`(A !== B && A !== C)` will evaluate to `(true && false)`, which will evaluate to `(false)` (**both** conditions are *not* met).

`(A !== B || A !== C)` will (short circuiting aside) evaluate to `(true || false)`, which will in turn evaluate to `(true)` (**one of** the conditions *is* met).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. :)